# Select unique combinations on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012. I cannot select distinct on more than one column, and I have limited permissions.

With this sample data

```
orderNum    CustomerNum OrderDesc   Structure
-------     ----------  --------    --------
001          456        repair      House
002          456        paint       House
003          678        repair      Fence
004          789        repair      House
005          789        paint       House
006          789        repair      Fence
007          789        paint       Fence
```

I want to write a query to show each unique structure being worked on, i.e. each unique combination of CustomerNum and Structure. I don't care if a structure is being painted or repaired or both.

So I am looking for results like:

```
orderNum    CustomerNum OrderDesc   Structure
-------     ----------  --------    --------
001          456        repair      House
003          678        repair      Fence
004          789        repair      House
006          789        repair      Fence
```

Note that two orderNums appear for CustomerNum 789 because House and Fence are both being worked on. However, I do not want CustomerNum 789 to appear 4 times.

What I have done to achieve this is
Select *
from Orders

Then paste into Excel and remove duplicates with both CustomerNum and Structure checked. But I am sure there must be a way to do this without Excel.

Comment: The use of a CTE does not require any special permissions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customernum, structure order by ordernum) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: My actual data starts at 4658 rows, when I remove duplicates in Excel based on CustomerNum and Structure I am left with 4478. This is the result I am expecting. 

When I use this query, I only retrieve 512 rows. The only thing I added to this query is a few more basic filters to the where clause. I believe it should still work if I change the last line to: 
Where seqnum = 1 and column1 = 'x' and column2 like '%y%'

Comment: @SeanM . . . It should work.  But those filters might be removing more rows than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of getting minimum ordernumber, minimum orderdescription for each customer, structure.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(orderNum    char(3), CustomerNum int, OrderDesc varchar(10),  Structure varchar(10))

insert into @table values

('004',          789        ,'repair'      ,'House'),
('005',          789        ,'paint'       ,'House'),
('006',          789        ,'repair'      ,'Fence'),
('007',          789        ,'paint'       ,'Fence');

select customernum, structure, min(ordernum) AS ordernum, Min(OrderDesc) as orderDesc
from @table
group by customernum, structure
```

| customernum | structure | ordernum | orderDesc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 789 | Fence | 006 | paint |
| 789 | House | 004 | paint |